# Boost Interprocess Condition Variable example doesn't compile

Tags: c++, boost, ipc

I'm trying to add `IPC` `condition variable`.

I took the example from the `Synchronization mechanisms` guide: [condition variable example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.conditions.conditions_anonymous_example), but it doesn't compile.

The error is in the line:

```
data->cond_full.wait(lock);
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/interprocess/sync/detail/locks.hpp: In instantiation of 'boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::internal_mutex_lock<Lock>::operator boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::internal_mutex_lock<Lock>::unspecified_bool_type() const [with Lock = std::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex>; boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::internal_mutex_lock<Lock>::unspecified_bool_type = void (boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::internal_mutex_lock<std::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex> >::*)()]':
/usr/local/include/boost/interprocess/sync/posix/condition.hpp:66:11:   required from 'void boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::posix_condition::wait(L&) [with L = boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::internal_mutex_lock<std::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex> >]'
/usr/local/include/boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_condition.hpp:99:23:   required from 'void boost::interprocess::interprocess_condition::wait(L&) [with L = std::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex>]'
/tmp/tmp.x5x2qaWhw5/test.h:88:25:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/interprocess/sync/detail/locks.hpp:50:17: error: could not convert '((const boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::internal_mutex_lock<std::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex> >*)this)->boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::internal_mutex_lock<std::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex> >::l_' from 'std::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex>' to 'bool'
   50 |    {  return l_ ? &internal_mutex_lock::lock : 0;  }
      |              ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 |
      |                 std::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex>
```

`Boost version` 1.78.0

`cpp` 20

`Linux` Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

`Arch` aarch64

Comment: From the error message it looks `lock` type is `std::scoped_lock`. I guess, it is expected to be `boost::interprocess::scoped_lock`.

Comment: Thanks @dewaffled, This was the issue. I'm immersed that I missed it. This is another example of why `using namespace std` is so BAD